# Simple git post-commit hook to copy committed files to a certain folder

Tags: git, deployment, githooks, post-commit, post-commit-hook

I would like to automatically copy the committed files to a certain folder so they can be viewed in a browser, but I would like to do this without having to create a bare repository that mirrors the main repository (as shown [here](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)) and I would like this to happen on commit.

Is there any simple way to create a hook that reads which files have been committed and copies them/updates them on a live webserver?

For example: I have a folder named /example.com and a git repository. I want that when I commit index.html in the repository, the corresponding index.html file from /example.com to be updated with the contents of the committed file

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A good way of doing this is to create a `post-commit` that runs `git checkout -f` with the work tree set to the directory that is exposed by your web server and the git directory set to the `.git` directory in your development repository.  For example, you could create a `.git/hooks/post-commit` file that did:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/example.com/
export GIT_DIR=/home/whoever/development/web-project/.git/
git checkout -f
```

Be careful with this, however - the `-f` means that git may remove or overwrite files to make `/example.com/` match the tree in your most recent commit.

(Remember to make the `.git/hooks/post-commit` file executable as well.)

Comment: On windows, is the script expecting full paths and what is the syntax? Thanks!

Comment: @andli I'm using msysgit, and it works using the same paths you would use in a git bash window.

Comment: Does this rewrite all the files or just the new ones? I have a very large repo and don't want to copy them all up every time.