# Git deploy on MediaTemple DV

Tags: git, mirror, mediatemple

I have a MediaTemple dv Server and a project versioned with Git I would like to deploy.
The situation is the following:

- I develop the site on my local machine.
- I commit changes on my local git repo (repoA)
- I push changes to the online repository (repoB) via Tower (http://www.git-tower.com)
  (the repository is in a folder not accessible via http)

I would like to automatically mirror from the remote repository (repoB) to a public html folder located at /var/www/vhosts/hostname.com/foldername

How could I automate the process?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-documented, easily-automated workflow. Essentially you're looking for server side git hooks. Try these as starting points:

- [Simple git post-commit hook to copy committed files to a certain folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633299/simple-git-post-commit-hook-to-copy-committed-files-to-a-certain-folder)
- [Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do this a few months back and was finally able to piece it together from pages that are too advanced and vague responses from this site. I finally got it down and explained it for the not so advanced user. I was setting mine up on a mediatemple grid server, so yours should be similar. It's written for someone not familiar with the whole command line process. See if it helps. Good luck.

[Deploying with git](http://jmorgan.ws/index.php/deploying-with-git-part-1/)