# Adding existing local git repo - Zend studio

Tags: eclipse, git, zend-studio

I have local git repo, which i'd like to add to my projects as a `GIT PHP Project`.

My workspace is at `C:\www` and repo is at `C:\www\citest` which is a existing git repo.

Now when i try to create project from git like so

```
Project Name: citest
Location: C:\www
URI: file:///C:\www\citest
```

then i get following error:

`C:\www\citest overlaps the location of another project: 'citest'`

But `C:\www\citest` **is not** zend porject. It is olny a git repo.

So far i've tried File > Import, with no results.

Then i tried to put `citest/` folder outside from my workspace, initialized new git project, deleted project from zend, copied `citest/` folder back to `www/` and tried to import existing project. It worked, but it didn't have git functionality.

How can i create **git project** from existing git local repo so it the folder ends up in my workspace `C:\www` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather keep the git repo well separated from the http workspace in term of eclipse project.

You can manage your git repo as a php project, and add a *clone* of that repo in your `c:\www` workspace.

Then a `post-commit` hook (in the git repo managed by Eclipse) can checkout automatically any commit you would do in your Eclipse project (checkout in the git repo in your `c:\www` workspace).
See for instance "[Simple git post-commit hook to copy committed files to a certain folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633299/simple-git-post-commit-hook-to-copy-committed-files-to-a-certain-folder)".