# Setting up control system for website

Tags: php, wordpress, git, ftp, web

I have been working on a website using Wordpress. So far I have been using FTP and the wordpress editor to make changes to the code etc. I have brought on a few members to assist me with changing code, and I am wondering what the best way would be to control changes. I know git can be used for this sort of stuff, but how can I make it so they can't make changes to the server without going through git?

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't give access to the server, handle all access through git.

You could set up a post-commit hook that copies the updated files to the server / pulls them from the repository to the server. See for example this question: [Simple git post-commit hook to copy committed files to a certain folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633299/simple-git-post-commit-hook-to-copy-committed-files-to-a-certain-folder)