# How to Execute the script after run the commit command in `git`

Tags: git

I want to execute script after run the commit command in `git`.

Comment: This previous SO answer contains a good sample:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633299/simple-git-post-commit-hook-to-copy-committed-files-to-a-certain-folder

Answer (score 6):

Now, I have got the answers,  Using Git hooks that executes before or after events such as: commit, push, and receive. http://githooks.com/