# Copy the committed git file to another folder

Tags: git, github

Is possible to copy only files committed to git repo to another folder. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633299/simple-git-post-commit-hook-to-copy-committed-files-to-a-certain-folder), however the solution provided copies the whole repo to another folder. I just want copy the committed files. 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain your use case more extensively ?

Comment: We need to build deployment package on the basis of the updated files. For example we want to combine some of the copied files as a one deployment package and deploy them together to the different environments.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `git archive` :

```
git archive -o archive.tgz <commit>
```

will create a tgz with all the files present in the selected commit